# Can't check if user authenticated or not react native + firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

 componentDidMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'Main' : 'Login')
})
}
```

this is my App.js where I want to check user authenticated or not

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: 'xyz',
authDomain: 'xyz',
databaseURL: 'xyz',
projectId: 'xyz',
storageBucket: 'xyz',
messagingSenderId: 'xyz'
 }

 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

 export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component{

state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
}

handleChangeUsername = (email) => {
    this.setState({email})
}
handleChangePassword = (password) => {
    this.setState({password})
}

loginUser = (email, password) => {
    console.log(email)
    console.log(password)
    try {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
            console.log("Success")
        })
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Main")
    }catch(error) {
        console.log(error.toString())
    }
}
```

And this is my LoginScreen. The problem is that in App.js it is saying undefined is not object (this.props.navigation.navigate)

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a navigation issue,if you want to check if your user is being authenticated just comment out  this.props.navigation.navigate("Main") and open your firebase console on authentication tab,check on users and see if you have a new user there.

Or you can just use your debuger and see the console logs of your authentication